# Correct way to run two tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I was wondering if this approach for running two long running operations in parallel and then getting their result is correct and if there would be any advantage to use async/await instead.

```
        public int DoStuff()
        {
            var res1 = Task.Run(() => LongRunning1());
            var res2 = Task.Run(() => LongRunning2());

            Task.WhenAll(res1, res2);
            return res1.Result + res2.Result;
        }

        int LongRunning1()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(30);
            return 10;
        }

        int LongRunning2()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            return 20;
        }
```

Comment: Is there anything else going on during those two long running operations?

Comment: Are the long running oprations IO or CPU bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running tasks in parallel this way is fine. The `WhenAll` line does nothing and can be removed. Also note that `Result` will wrap any exceptions in `AggregateException`; this is normal when running parallel code.

```
public int DoStuff()
{
  var res1 = Task.Run(() => LongRunning1());
  var res2 = Task.Run(() => LongRunning2());

  return res1.Result + res2.Result;
}
```

However, if the tasks are naturally asynchronous (e.g., I/O-bound), then you can do *concurrent asynchronous* code instead of *parallel* code:

```
async Task<int> LongRunning1Async()
{
  await Task.Delay(30);
  return 10;
}

async Task<int> LongRunning2Async()
{
  await Task.Delay(10);
  return 20;
}

public async Task<int> DoStuffAsync()
{
  var res1 = LongRunning1Async();
  var res2 = LongRunning2Async();

  return await res1 + await res2;
}
```

or, alternatively:

```
public async Task<int> DoStuffAsync()
{
  var res1 = LongRunning1Async();
  var res2 = LongRunning2Async();

  var results = await Task.WhenAll(res1, res2);
  return results[0] + results[1];
}
```

Comment: the tasks are http requests. is async/await still recommended? what is the advantage versus the .Result approach?

Comment: @Cyan: HTTP requests are I/O, so yes, you should use asynchronous concurrency instead of parallelism. The advantage is that you use fewer threads to accomplish the same result.

Comment: one more question @Stephen: on your blog here http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html you're saying .Result can cause deadlocks. Why wouldn't it in the code above?

Comment: @Cyan: The first code example is using [task parallelism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx), where `Result` is appropriate (and won't deadlock because the tasks are actually running *synchronous code* on *other threads*). The second two examples are using asynchronous concurrency, where `Result` should be replaced with `await`.

Comment: one last question: In the examples above, you use await on the Task.Delay. What if I don't have a Task inside them and I run a synchronous http request? In that case I don't have other options than creating my own task with Task.Run, correct? I cannot make LongRunningTask async in some other way, can I? Or I guess I should use the async versions of the requests?

Comment: @Cyan: You should use the asynchronous APIs if possible. This allows you to use asynchronous concurrency, which scales much better than parallelism. But if you use synchronous APIs, then you can use parallelism.